# How to pass scope from directive to template

Tags: angularjs

I can't understand how to pass my scope object from directive to template, i need to change background my div, i did like this:

```
var app = angular.module('comments', []);
app.controller('fooCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.bg= {};
})

app.directive('foo', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function(){
                scope.bg= {background: 'blue'};  
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and:

```
<div ng-app="comments">
    <div ng-controller="fooCtrl">
        <foo>foo</foo>
        <foo>foo</foo>
        <foo>foo</foo>
        <foo>foo</foo>
        <div id="form" ng-style="bg"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But this is not working.

It's probably so funny question, and my code is awful, but it my first Angular app. Hope for your help.

Comment: You are calling `scope` outside of directive context.

Comment: i dont see any issue here, its working fine https://plnkr.co/edit/t0wYLr6XQ5llMxQgqyeq?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use controller attribute in the directive to pass the current controller scope to directive, then change the value of the controller and use $timeout to update the value back to original controller. please check the sample

```js
angular.module('testApp', [])
            .directive('foo', function($timeout) {
                return {
                    restrict: "E",
                    scope: {
                        controller: '=',
                        color: '@'
                    },
                    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                        element.bind('click', function() {
                            $timeout(function() {
                              scope.controller.bg = {
                                   background: scope.color
                               };
                            });
                        });
                    }
                };
            })
            .controller('AppCtrl', function () {});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="testApp">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl as vm">
      <foo controller="vm" color="red">foo</foo>
      <foo controller="vm" color="black">foo</foo>
      <foo controller="vm" color="blue">foo</foo>
      <foo controller="vm" color="yellow">foo</foo>


        <div id="form" ng-style="vm.bg">
            {{vm.bg.background}}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! Unfortunately i can't to vote for you answer :(

Comment: Can you explain why to have $timeout here.

Comment: `$timeout` to fire the angular digest cycle, to update new values to original controller values

Comment: $time out is not a better Practice to Use

Comment: @gayathri could you please enplane, why `$timeout` is not the best practice in this case? or please refer to documentation

Answer (score 1):

Better try this way

**HTML**

```
<foo data-method="ctrlFn">foo</foo>
        <foo data-method="ctrlFn">foo</foo>
        <foo data-method="ctrlFn">foo</foo>
        <foo data-method="ctrlFn">foo</foo>
        <div id="form" ng-style="bg" >{{bg.background}}</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
          $scope.bg= {};
          $scope.ctrlFn = function(arg) {  
        $scope.bg = arg;
        $scope.$apply();
    }
});


app.directive('foo', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            fromDirectiveFn: '=method'
        },
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
          elm.bind("click", function(e){
         var bg= {background: 'blue'}; 
            scope.fromDirectiveFn(bg);
       });
        }
    }
});
```

data-method="ctrlFn" from the Directive create the scope name called fromDirectiveFn using that uyou can call the controller Function ctrlFn for ref https://plnkr.co/edit/XLtahJNwTDP2T3s8Gok0?p=preview